# Correct Russian keyboard layout: Toshiba M70-350 + Xubuntu 14.04

Tags: xubuntu, keyboard, input, internationalization, russian

Just as said in the title, is it possible to get a ready, correct keyboard layout for this ancient laptop and install it? Those layouts available with the distro don't get the `,` `.` etc. right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pure guess, but you may want to give it a try:

Install the **ibus-m17n** package, log out and log in again. That way a few more Russian input sources become available. Possibly some of those fits your laptop better.

Comment: Your answer pointed me in the right direction. After installing ibus-m17n, I checked input Methods in "Language Support" and realized it was set to "none" (whatever it means; I was switching b/w langauages before). Changed it to IBus, added Russian language input in IBus settings, logged out and in - now everything is worked as it's supposed to.